# qemu running Ubuntu Core mouse does not create /dev/input/eventxx

Tags: ubuntu, arm, qemu

I am trying to set up an armel Ubuntu Core to run under QEMU

Host: Ubuntu 12.04
Guest: ARM

I followed the section "Download a pre-built image" here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RootfsFromScratch . The actual image file came from:
http://w3.impa.br/~gabrield/data/ubuntu-arm-development-rootfs.tar.bz2

There is good news: it comes up fine, the console interface works fine, the keyboard works fine. I can even get the framebuffer to display graphics in the terminal.

But now I'd like to get the mouse interface working. In no case does the device file

```
/dev/input/eventx
```

ever get created. Right now

```
dmesg | grep input
```

only shows /dev/input/event0 which is the keyboard (works fine).

I've installed mdetect, and other mouse related utilities and none of them detect the mouse.

I have tried many things on the QEMU front:
- qemu command line parameter to start up usb, add usb drivers
- qemu monitor commands to set the mouse

With or without "-usb" or "-device usbhost" on the qemu command line, lsusb still does not return anything.

I have searched for forums and google for any help but I could not find anything that helped out.

My understanding is that any newer ubuntu kernel have mouse support built in. So it should detect a PS/2 or USB mouse with no problem.

Any help, tips or knowledge will be greatly appreciated!